# iCloud query lists deleted files

Tags: ios, file, icloud

In my app creates a file on iCloud (outside of the Documents container). This works fine.
I wanted to test the presence/absence of that file. So I built up a NSMetadataQuery that actually detects the file when it is in the cloud. No problem.

Now, I deleted all my apps data from the cloud (using the System preferences), as well as all instances of my app.

Built from scratch and launched the app again. The query is **still** detecting the file, though it obviously doesn't exist any more, any where...

Any idea how I can get a "correct" file list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what the iCloud service thinks is correct, visit https://developer.icloud.com/ and browse around. That will show the server-side view of the iCloud account.